# Component communication using @Input() not working in angular7

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a member list page,it shows members with their names and profile picture.If I click any of member,then it route to another page with the user id and show user info.I used view resolver to get the user data by that user Id

And there is a another button for view currently logged user profile.I used same page with the current user id to show that user info.

In this page I added sub pages to show user photos, videos, etc.
these are the pages/

```
<app-member-info [user]="user"></app-member-info>
<app-photo-card [user]="user" (getMemberPhotoChange)="updateMainPhoto($event)"></app-photo-card>
<app-photo-album-list [user]="user"> </app-photo-album-list>
<app-video-editor [videos]="user.videos" [user]="user"></app-video-editor>
```

These pages to pass that view resolver return user object.

My problem is If I view member details from members list,then it shows that user all informations.After that if I click current user view profile button,then it's not getting current users details to show photos and videos.But it shows this page data

```
 <app-member-info [user]="user"></app-member-info>
```

Here is my html code for member details page

```
    <div class="container mt-4">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="tab-panel">
        <tabset [justified]="true" >
          <tab heading="About {{user?.firstName}}">
            <app-member-info [user]="user"></app-member-info>
          </tab>
         <tab heading="Photos">
            <div *ngIf="authService.currentUser && authService.currentUser.id == user.id" class="row  mb-1">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" title="Upload Photos" class="btn btn-default pull-right upload-img-btn" (click)="openModal(template)">Upload Photos</button>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tab-panel">
                  <tabset class="member-tabset">
                    <tab *ngIf="authService.currentUser && authService.currentUser.id == user.id" heading="Your Photos">
                      <app-photo-card [user]="user" (getMemberPhotoChange)="updateMainPhoto($event)"></app-photo-card>
                    </tab>
                    <tab *ngIf="(authService.currentUser && authService.currentUser.id != user.id) || authService.currentUser == undefined" heading="{{user.userName}}'s Photos'">
                      <app-photo-card [user]="user" (getMemberPhotoChange)="updateMainPhoto($event)"></app-photo-card>
                    </tab>

                    <tab heading="Photo Albums">
                      <app-photo-album-list [user]="user"> </app-photo-album-list>
                    </tab>


                  </tabset>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </tab>
          <tab heading="Videos">
              <app-video-editor [videos]="user.videos" [user]="user"></app-video-editor>
             </tab>
          <tab heading="Recommendations">
            <app-recommendations [toRecommendUser]="user"></app-recommendations>
          </tab>
        </tabset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is typescript code for member details page

```
export class MemberDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;


  constructor(
    private router: Router, private modalService: BsModalService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data['user'];
    }); }}
```

**Update:**
here is the view resolver code

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberDetailsResolver implements Resolve<User> {
    values$: any;
    constructor(private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
        return this.userService.getUser(route.params['id']).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving user details');
                this.router.navigate(['/members']);
                return of(null);
            })
        );
    }


}
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?
I want to do this without page refresh.If I refresh page then it's working
thanks

Comment: Are you sure this works ok `this.route.data.subscribe(data => { this.user = data['user'];  });`? What does the `user` get set to? The problem is almost surely not at the `@Input`. Try to provide minimal code that reproduces your issue on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Andrew, thanks alot for your reply.
Yest it's working, I used view resolver to pass data.I updated my code.It contains view resolver code
I didn't use stackblits because, I have to add photos and videos for some pages

Comment: It's hard to track what the issue is with these bits and pieces. You don't have to put up the entire code, only some mock components that reproduce your issue. You can also use Augury (https://augury.rangle.io/) to better debug angular in the browser.